# An error occurred trying to start process '/usr/bin/bash' No such file or directory

Tags: flutter, dart, github-actions, firebase-hosting

Here's my workflow:

```yaml
name: Build and Release APK
on: push
jobs:
    hosting:
      name: Deploy Website
      runs-on: ubuntu-latest
      steps:        
        # Checkout Repository
       # - uses: actions/checkout@v3

        # Install Flutter command
         - name: Set up Flutter
           uses: subosito/flutter-action@v2
           with:
             channel: 'stable'
             flutter-version: '3.10.5'

         - uses: webfactory/ssh-agent@v0.7.0
           with:
             ssh-private-key: ${{ secrets.SSH_KEY_GITHUB }}

        # Build Website
         - name: Build Website
           working-directory: ./apps/project1
           run: |
             flutter pub get
             flutter build web --release

        # Deploy Firebase Hosting
         - name: Deploy Firebase Hosting
           uses: w9sss/firebase-action@master
           with:
             args: deploy --only hosting:something
           env:
             FIREBASE_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_TOKEN }}
             PROJECT_PATH: ./apps/project1
```

And I am getting this error:

```
An error occurred trying to start process '/usr/bin/bash' with working directory '/home/runner/work/flutter/flutter/./apps/project1'. No such file or directory
```

Comment: Your checkout step is commented. Uncomment it and it should be fixed if that path exists.